# File Write Access Denied from ISAPI

Tags: delphi, iis, file-permissions, uac

I'm using Delphi/Intraweb to build an ISAPI file. I'm using Win7 on my local machine and Server2012 as the target deployment. I created a "Temp" folder under the "cgi-bin" folder. I'm attempting to output files to the "Temp" folder.

If on the "Temp" folder grant "write" permissions to "Everyone" my file write works. So I know it's a permissions issue. But for some reason granting "write" permissions to "IIS_IUSRS" does not work.

How do I find out what user IIS is using to execute the cgi, and better yet how do I change it to be IIS_IUSRS as I would expect.

w3wp.exe is running under "DefaultAppPool". Granting write access to "DefaultAppPool" still does not give me write permissions to the Temp folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, IIS versions on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 run the web application in an Application Pool and you can check/modify with the IIS administration console what user the `w3wp.exe` process(es) run(s) under in the Application Pool settings.

Comment: w3wp.exe is running under "DefaultAppPool". Granting write access to "DefaultAppPool" still does not give me write permissions to the Temp folder.

Comment: ?? That's not what I meant. Look in the app pool settings what identity is defined there. If I check on a server here, it's `ApplicationPoolIdentity` which means the user `DefaultAppPool` is not able to access the temp folder. http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Thank you for helping my reputation get up to 10000!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the permissions for IIS AppPool\"YourAppPoolName". You can find the YourAppPoolName value in the name property of the basic cofiguration of your application pool.

Also, I don't know if this is usual but in my server configuration, anonymous login was enabled using user IUSR. I had to add permissions for IUSR to access the folder as well. You can check the anonymous login user account in the authentication icon.